# Unable to get results for bank's fixed effect

Tags: r, plm

I am using following code with panel data. I am able to get the year fixed effect but I am unable to get the bank fixed effect. I am getting the bank effect by using lm but not by plm.

I am sharing the sample data :

[image: sample data]

```
p_data <- pdata.frame(data_1, index = c("id", "time"),drop.index = TRUE)

fixed1 <- plm(y ~ x, data=p_data, model="within")
summary(fixed1)

fixed2 <- plm(y ~ x + factor(year) - 1, data=p_data, model="within")
summary(fixed2)

fixed3 <- plm(y ~ x + factor(bank) - 1, data=p_data, model="within")
summary(fixed3)

fixed4 <- plm(y ~ x + factor(year) + factor(bank) - 1, data = p_data, model="within")
summary(fixed4)
```

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fixed3` already is a bank fixed effects model as the default fixed effects are the individual effects (in your case id eq. to bank; it is just coded differently). Look at these two models for bank fixed effects:

```
fixed3.1 <- plm(y ~ x + factor(bank) - 1, data=p_data, model="pooling")
summary(fixed3.1)

fixed3.2 <- plm(y ~ x, data=p_data, model="within")
summary(fixed3.2)
fixef(fixed3.2)
```

For a two-ways model, look at:

```
fixed4.tw <- plm(y ~ x, data = p_data, model="within", effect = "twoways")
summary(fixed4.tw)
fixef(fixed4.tw)
fixef(fixed4.tw, effect = "time")
fixef(fixed4.tw, effect = "twoways")
```

Comment: I am not getting the effects of individual banks in fixed4.tw like it is displaying in fixed3.1. like this:
                   Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
x                   -2.6330     1.2434 -2.1175 0.0346349 *  
factor(bank)ALD    125.6838    62.3488  2.0158 0.0442727 *  
factor(bank)ANDH   128.2210    62.3488  2.0565 0.0401734 *  
factor(bank)AXIS   210.9056    62.7811  3.3594 0.0008317 ***
factor(bank)BNDH   142.8851    73.7119  1.9384 0.0530487 .

Comment: fixed4.tw is a twoways model, unlike fixed3.1, which is a one-way model. For twoway models, the effects of the two dimensions will be different compared to the respective one-way effects (not a coding remark though, you might want to read up on the theory of one-way and two-way models). However, looking at the examples in `?plm::fixef` might could be sufficient if you just want some example calculations.